# Parsing a price with , and ,-- exception with parseFloat()

Tags: javascript, parsing, parsefloat

I'm trying to parse a price out of a html document:

Here is how the HTML element looks like:

```
<div>
<span id="market_buynow_dialog_totals_total"  class="market_dialog_totals_cost">0,11€</span>
<span class="market_dialog_totals_label">Total:</span>
</div>
```

There is a `,` and I don't want to be restricted to either the left or the right side of the `,`, in the example above I would love to get the int 11 and for 399,99 I would love to get 39999.

Here is my current solution:

```
var currentPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("market_buynow_dialog_totals_total").innerHTML.replace(/[,€]/g, ""));
```

However there is an exception that breaks my little solution: The price can be 300,-- or 250,-- too at times. In this cases `currentPrice`is 300 or 250 instead of the desired 30000 or 25000.

I'm trying to find an elegant and especially short solution for this problem. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var currentPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("market_buynow_dialog_totals_total").innerHTML.replace(/[,€]/g, "").replace(/\D/g,'0'));
```

This will convert any remaining non-integers into 0's.

Comment: Short, smart and just perfect. Thanks a lot.

As I want to get better in programming as well and not only ask for help, what would you say would have been the best way to find this on my own? I'm missing like the JAVA APi for JS, any site you could suggest?

Comment: Google is your best friend. First figure out how you want to solve a problem, then just look up how to do it. That's my usual approach, anyways. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You might try replacing the "--" part with "00" - just insert the replace before the ,€ part.